# Why are there so many improper underlines when I debugging python code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have been writing my python code in VSCode with a python extension named 'python' on Ubuntu for many days. It has been very nice.

However, today I meet some problems as shown in the picture:

[image]

I have write the correct code which can be run properly (both for debugging and running through the Terminal). But there are many green underlines and a few red underlines which give many tips as:

for green underlines:

> - C0326:No space allowed before bracket (pylint)
> - W0621:Redefining name 'img' from outer scope (line 60) (pylint)
> - C0103:Invalid variable name "c" (pylint)
> - C0326:Exactly one space required after comma (pylint)
> - C0303:Trailing whitespace (pylint)
> - and so on

for red underlines:

> E0602:Undefined variable 'Runtime' (pylint)
>
> Unspecified run-time error.

It seems this occured since I pressed one shortcut key accidentally, but I don't know which key it is.

How can I get rid of these underlines?

Comment: Those are actual errors and warnings your editor is showing to you. Instead of ignoring them (and turning off those warnings), you should actually fix them. So just go through them one-by-one and fix the issues.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly modifications and suggestions. In fact, my program didn't give any errors or warnings yesterday. This situation only happens today. So I'm sure there is no problem with my program but only with the vscode editor itself.

Comment: Just because the extension wasn’t showing the warnings and errors before, that doesn’t mean that your program is/was correct. Those issues, especially that red one, highlight real problems your program has.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I want to know how we can make the extension work not so strictly as to hint all warnings of the program.

Answer (score 9):

I'm the author of the extension. An updated was pushed out on the 9th of June. It is possible you hadn't updated for a while. To get rid of these messages you could either fix the corresponding errors or just turn off linting by going into the settings.json file and adding the following setting:

```
"python.linting.enabled":false
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome extension and kind answer. In fact, I have used the method you mentioned to disable the pylint. However, this will disable the pylint totally. So I wonder if there is a way to make the pylint not so strict to give the hint. For example, it will give the hints of the errors and some warnings, but wont give the hints of invalid variable name or about 'space' before the bracket. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, you can configure pylint, by placing a pylint config file within the root directory of your project (i.e. your work space). This way you can choose to ignore certain messages.

Comment: OK, I will have a try. Thank you very much.

Comment: Disabling it doesn't fix it.  I've imported gtk in mine and it says anything to do with gtk is an error and the member doesn't exist, but it does.